# How can I use Google Natural Language API to enrich data in a Bigquery table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to use data stored in a BigQuery table as input to [Google's Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language), perform entity extraction and sentiment analysis, and persist the result back to BigQuery. What tools/services could I use to handle this in GCP? Performance is not a concern, and running this in an overnight batch would be acceptable for this use-case.

Comment: Check out Cloud Next '19 session [Viant’s Journey:The Non-Engineer Guide to BigQuery (Cloud Next '19)](https://youtu.be/BpgW27YLSS8) - specifically episode about [enriching image data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpgW27YLSS8&feature=youtu.be&t=1360) in BigQuery using Vision API. Obviously in the same manner any Rest API can be used, including Natural Language API. You can find more demos [here](https://potensio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward to do with Dataflow--you could write a pipeline that [reads from BigQuery](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#reading-from-bigquery) followed by a [DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) that uses [Google's NLP Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/quickstart-client-libraries), and then [writes the results to BigQuery](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-bigquery).

Some wrappers are already provided for you in https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/ml/gcp/naturallanguageml.py